# ajaxForm after submit goes to php page instead of staying

Tags: jquery, html, forms, ajaxform

I'm trying to use an ajaxForm for submit 10 forms in one page.
So I tryed this steps,but in first time that I open my page, ajaxForm does not work and goes to php page (a white page) instead of staying!

1- I added jquery and jqueryForm:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

2- Define ajaxForm() for every my forms:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#formP2').ajaxForm(function() {
           alert("Page 2 submitted!");
           $('#page02').collapsible('collapse');
           $('#page03').show();
           $('#page03').collapsible('expand');
       });
       $('#formP3').ajaxForm(function() {
           alert("Page 3 submitted!");
           $('#page03').collapsible('collapse');
           $('#page04').show();
           $('#page04').collapsible('expand');
       }); 
...}
```

3- I write my forms:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="php/formUserP1.php" 
id="formP1" name="formP1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" class="form-control dont-print" data-icon="arrow-l" data-inline="true" name="next02" id="next02">
</form>
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="php/formUserP2.php" id="formP2" name="formP2">
</form>
...
```

In first time, This is not work. When I submit any form, page goes to php file and a white page. But when I refresh page this works well!
Please help me!

Comment: did you include your ajaxForms in $(document).ready(function() { }?

Comment: Yes, i edit it now.

Comment: For me it works in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/pLa7595j/4/ I just had to add the submit callback, since there is no comment.php which could send back a success Header. Take a look in your js console to see if there are errors.

Comment: @mondjunge Thank you but what is different between .ajaxForm() and .submit() ? Why you used both in your code?

Comment: I just took a look at the examples at http://malsup.com/jquery/form/, maybe you should read them yourself, it answers your questions.